# How to make a Filestream Appear in Stackpanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been able to save the **XAML** into a file and then re-open the **XAML** on a different window. I have now added a **Stackpanel** for the **Filestream** to be put into but an error seems to be coming out on my code.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Ben Clarke\Desktop\file.txt", FileMode.Open);
    XamlReader.Load(fs);
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
    panel.Children.Add(fs);

}
```

**The line `panel.Children.Add(fs);` seem to be coming out with an error saying:**

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(System.Windows.UIElement)' has some invalid arguments
```

**Also says this one to:**

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'
```

**Could somone please help me on this situation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Ben Clarke\Desktop\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
    panel.Children.Add((UIElement)XamlReader.Load(fs));
}
```

Of course, this will throw `InvalidCastException` at runtime, if XAML doesn't contain `UIElement` as its root.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deleted the instantiation of Stackpanel and changed Panel to the name of my stackpanal on the Window and it showed.